# Should global costmap have an obstacle layer when using a SLAM node?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, c++, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build a navigation system, but am a bit confused about the configuration of my global costmap for move_base.

I am using gmapping to create a map of the environment, which is published to /map.

I want global_costmap to use this map while planning, so I set static_map to true.

I find that global_costmap will load an obstacle layer and inflation layer by default.

Should I keep the obstacle layer? Wouldn't it just be redundant with the gmapping?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216076/should-global-costmap-have-an-obstacle-layer-when-using-a-slam-node?/) by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 363 on 2015-08-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree that it would most likely be redundant in the global_costmap, so you should not keep it.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) on 2015-08-19**:
Thank you very much.

**Comment by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on 2017-03-23**:
Wouldn't it make sense to keep the obstacle layer, given it uses a VoxelLayer (2.5d obstacle info) while the SLAM node (gmapping) might not?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2017-03-26**:
If the obstacle layer is a voxel layer, then possibly it might not be redundant.